# Getting the error : TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following sample data:

```
x = [[0, 0],[1, 0],[1, 0], [0, 1],[0, 1],[0, 0],[1, 1],[1, 0],[0, 0],[1, 0],[1, 0],[0, 1],[1, 1],[0, 0],[1, 1],[1, 1],[0, 1],[1, 0],[1, 1],[0, 1],[1, 1]]
y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I'm trying to create a mask for the data in y using the data in x
So,

```
mask = (x[:,1] == 1)  #True at all the indices at which the value of attribute1 is 1 in the observations (x)
y_left = y[mask]  #all the observations which have attribute1 == 1 will go in left child
```

When I try to run this in isolation then it gives me the error which is the subject line of this question:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
Not sure what wrong I'm doing here. if someone has any idea please help.

Comment: make `np.array(x)` ...

Comment: The syntax you're trying to use is not applicable to Python lists

Answer (score 0):

As [RomanPerekhrest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185459/romanperekhrest) and [Pingu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17580381/pingu) said, you should use NumPy arrays because Python lists do not support this syntax:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0, 0],[1, 0],[1, 0], [0, 1],[0, 1],[0, 0],[1, 1],[1, 0],[0, 0],[1, 0],[1, 0],[0, 1],[1, 1],[0, 0],[1, 1],[1, 1],[0, 1],[1, 0],[1, 1],[0, 1],[1, 1]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

mask = (x[:,1] == 1)
y_left = y[mask]
print(y_left)
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

# If you need a Python list:
print(y_left.tolist())
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```